# Loop for concatenating similar lists in the list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I wrote a loop that compares list of the lists. If it founds two similar lists, it sums up one of their strings and removes the second list. Is there a way to make it more correct?

Input list:

```
someList = [['abc', 'def', 10, 'ghi'], ['abc', 'def', 50, 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr']]
```

Code:

```
a = 0
for i in range(len(someList)):
    for k in range(len(someList)):
        if someList[i] != someList[k]:
            if someList[i][0] == someList[k][0]:
                if someList[i][1] == someList[k][1]:
                        if someList[i][4] == someList[k][4]:
                            someList[i][2] = someList[i][2] + someList[k][2]
                            someList[k][4] = 'lalala'
                            a = k
del someList[a]
```

Desired output list is:

```
someList = [['abc', 'def', 60, 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr']]
```

This code works but I it's very badly written. Furthermore it works if only 2 similar sublists are in the list.

Comment: Reading the code, it is iterating over the same list twice and comparing each element with each other? And the list is two dimensional? It's not clear what the code is trying to do so perhaps show an example input list and the code's desired output.

Comment: @danny Okay, I corrected the post.

Comment: What makes sublists 'similar'?

Comment: @zwer equal items [0], [1] and [3] (except [2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do that with a temporary lookup map:

```
someList = [['abc', 'def', 10, 'ghi'], ['abc', 'def', 50, 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr']]

lookup_map = {}
for e1, e2, e3, e4 in someList:
    key = (e1, e2, e4)
    if key in lookup_map:
        lookup_map[key][2] += e3
    else:
        lookup_map[key] = [e1, e2, e3, e4]

print(lookup_map.values())
# [['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr'], ['abc', 'def', 60, 'ghi']]
```

finishes in *O(N)* time. If you need to preserve the order, use `collections.OrderedDict` for your `lookup_map`. Also, this can be more memory efficient if you store only the keys and have the third element increase as a value like:

```
import collections

someList = [['abc', 'def', 10, 'ghi'], ['abc', 'def', 50, 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr']]

lookup_map = collections.defaultdict(int)
for e1, e2, e3, e4 in someList:
    lookup_map[e1, e2, e4] += e3

# but now we need to unpack it back into a list:
result = [[e1, e2, v, e3] for (e1, e2, e3), v in lookup_map.items()]
# [['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr'], ['abc', 'def', 60, 'ghi']]
```

Or if you don't want to use `collections.defaultdict` (and you should, it would be faster for larger datasets):

```
someList = [['abc', 'def', 10, 'ghi'], ['abc', 'def', 50, 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr']]

lookup_map = {}
for e1, e2, e3, e4 in someList:
    key = (e1, e2, e4)
    lookup_map[key] = lookup_map.get(key, 0) + e3

# but now we need to unpack it back to a list:
result = [[e1, e2, v, e3] for (e1, e2, e3), v in lookup_map.items()]
# [['jkl', 'mno', 20, 'pqr'], ['abc', 'def', 60, 'ghi']]
```